# Formatted Output into columns

Tags: python, format, multiple-columns

So I am trying to write a function that requests 3 things an amount to be invested, the interest rate, and duration of the investment then outputs it into columns of year, interest, and total.

```
def figinvest():
    amount = eval(input("Please give me the amount invested: "))
    interest = eval(input("Please give me the current interest rate as a decimal: "))
    duration = eval(input("Please give me the duration of the investment: "))
    info = []
```

The output should look like:

```
Year  Interest   Total

 0      0.00     3000.00

 1     165.00    3165.00

 2     174.07    3339.07

etc.
```

List item

```
print( "Year  Interest  Total")
```

this is what I have so far. I am just stuck on how to go about using the inputs and putting them into the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ambiguous question. You must tell us which software, Language and tool you are using. So we can guide you.
From the code you have provided it is not obvious offcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Hi using only base python without any external libraries, i will store the results in a list of list.

```
## your function to ask for user input
def figinvest():
   amount = eval(input("Please give me the amount invested: "))
   interest = eval(input("Please give me the current interest rate as a decimal: "))
   duration = eval(input("Please give me the duration of the investment: "))
   return [amount, interest, duration]
```

maybe a while loop to keep asking the question so that you can keep asking the question till    the user decide to stop

```
all_reply = []
while True:
    ## ask question till user say N
    singleReply = figinvest()
    all_reply.append(singleReply)
    anotherInvestment = input("Will you like to enter another investment- Press N to quit")
    if anotherInvestment == "N" :
        break

print("Year\tInterest\tTotal")
for reply in all_reply:
    ## convert integer to string for join and print
    reply = [ str(x)  for x in reply]
    print("\t".join(reply))
```

Hope you find this useful as a general guide! Of course you may have to add in some logics to make sure your input will be in decimal and stuff but I cant do your job for you hehehe (and accept my answer =))